# How is Generalist badge supposed to work?

Tags: support, badges

> Provided non-wiki answers of 15 total score in 20 of top 40 tags.

http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/35591/generalist-progression-updated

(also, updated and improved query is 
http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/87003/user-generalist-progression-updated-and-include-which-tags-are-under-200-qs?UserId=976 )

That query shows me at >15 score in 28 of 40 top tags, but I don't have that badge (neither does anyone else).

Either I'm misreading the batch description, or I'm misreading the appropriate data exporer query, or the badge isn't enabled on SFF (I saw mentions of that being non-universal across sites on MSO). What's the reason?

Comment: It's been 18 months, and we still are nowhere near that badge being active.  We need more and better questions!!!

Comment: @Jeff - well, I tried repeatedly to make the site friendlier to question askers. [Including yesterday](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3488/should-some-vtc-reasons-on-questions-be-restricted-to-people-with-proven-questio). People don't seem to care about that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [the SO blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/generalist-badge-implemented/):

> One thing the badge doesn’t say, is that there must be at least 200 questions in all 40 of the top tags before this badge is awarded to anyone. That’s why you won’t see it on meta for a bit longer, or any new sites for about a year. I don’t feel you can accurately measure a generalist until the top tag list settles down.

#### Update:

As of yesterday, this badge is now being awarded. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/14/generalist

Comment: Thanks! We are a long ways off! I will edit in 2 queries I created to help answer "when"