# "unearned" badges filter should exclude Generalist badge for sites that don't have it enabled yet

Tags: bug, status-declined, badges

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=general&filter=unearned

The new filter seems to have a small bug/feature: it lists "Generalist" badge ("Provided non-wiki answers of 15 total score in 20 of top 40 tags"), which is **technically impossible to earn on SFF yet!** - see: [How is Generalist badge supposed to work?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2450/how-is-generalist-badge-supposed-to-work) on SFF meta for details.

The filter should either omit the badge for the sites where the badge is not turned on; or at least, explicitly mark it as "Not available for this site yet".

Comment: There are a number of impossible badges across the network, I'm not too fussed about this one. We'll get it eventually.

Comment: @Kevin - VERY eventually, if ever. [Query](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/87003/user-generalist-progression-updated-and-include-which-tags-are-under-200-qs?UserId=976)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Discussed and [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) on MSO

[Should unearnable Badges been shown under unearned?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185009/172958)